# The Klausenberger Rebbe: Parah Aduma and Torah study

Tags: commentaries, chukas, klausenberger

The Klausenberger Rebbe, [Yekusiel Yehudah Halberstam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yekusiel_Yehudah_Halberstam), in his sefer Shefa Chaim, on parashas Chukas, [explains](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36053&st=&pgnum=309) (I've heard in a online-shiur by Rav Daniel Glatstein, that the Klausenberger Rebbe said
this shiur while being in Auschwitz) that the first posuk in this week's parasha, tells you that the main goal of Torah study is to apply it IRL.

> ונראה דמצינו (קידושין מ' ע"ב) נענו כולם ואמרו תלמוד גדול שתלמוד מביא לידי מעשה, וזה עיקר תכלית הלימוד לדעת מה יעשה ישראל כדת של תורה והלכותיה. ועל זה נאמר (תהלים קיט, א) אשרי תמימי דרך ההולכים בתורת ה', שמקיימים והולכים על פי מה שלמדו בתורת ה'. וזהו אומרו, זאת חוקת התורה אשר צוה ה' לאמר, שעיקר חוקת התורה היא ללמוד ע"מ דבר אל בני ישראל וגו', גם במה שאמר זאת חוקת התורה ולא זאת חוקת לעשות ולקיים אלה המצוות אשר צוה ה'

How did the Klausenberger Rebbe come to the conclusion that the words [זֹ֚את חֻקַּ֣ת הַתּוֹרָ֔ה - Zos Chukas HaTorah (Bamidbar 19:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0) hint to us what the main goal of Torah study is? How does he come to this conclusion by reading the second posuk in parashas Chukas which tells us about the red heifer? He does cite the Gemara in [קידושין מ' ע"ב](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.40b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). But again, why does he connect it with parashas chukas, and the parah adumah?

Comment: Your link to Shefa Chaim doesn't say anything like that. It says the aim of Torah study should be to apply it in practice.

Comment: I changed it, read the wrong article :)

Comment: His yarhzeit today! ztl

Answer (score 4):

I think he's reading it like this:

This is the purpose of Torah study - זאת חוקת התורה

That you should fulfill what Hashem has commanded - אשר צוה ה' לאמר

Comment: Interesting. This is exactly what the Klausenberger says in the above mentioned page. I am, however, looking for an explanation as to how he did come to this conclusion based on the beginning words of the pesukim.